# Combining quarter and financial year columns into date column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I've got a pandas dataframe in which financial years are listed in a column, and the quarter is listed in another.

I'd like to combine them into a single column.

The format is:

```
Financial Year   Financial Quarter
2015/16          1
2015/16          1
```

I was planning to create a date column based on the Financial Year column, and then offset it by Financial Quarter.

My first step was:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Financial Year'], format="%Y/%y")
```

But I got a bit stuck with the second step.

Is there a better way to combine string data from multiple columns in one pass?

Comment: You're probably after [business quarters](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets) or [offset aliases](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) `BQS` I think

Comment: I suspect before moving on you have to decide on the format of the year, as FY `2015/16` appears to be too ambiguous. Pandas internally represents timestamps as # of seconds since `1970-01-01` and to do so it needs an exact point in time, not `2015/16`. As soon as you sort out this issue, there will be several ways to move forward, eg as @EdChum offered above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can first extract years from column `Financial Year` and then use [`BQuarterBegin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) and [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) it with columns `year1` and `year2`:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *

print df
  Financial Year  Financial Quarter
0        2015/16                  1
1        2015/16                  1

df[['year1', 'year2']] = pd.DataFrame([ x.split('/') for x in df['Financial Year'].tolist()])
df['year1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year1'], format="%Y") 
df['year2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year2'], format="%y") 
print df
  Financial Year  Financial Quarter      year1      year2
0        2015/16                  1 2015-01-01 2016-01-01
1        2015/16                  1 2015-01-01 2016-01-01

df['date1'] = df.apply(lambda x:(x['year1'] + BQuarterBegin(x['Financial Quarter'])), axis=1)
df['date2'] = df.apply(lambda x:(x['year2'] + BQuarterBegin(x['Financial Quarter'])), axis=1)
print df
  Financial Year  Financial Quarter      year1      year2      date1  \
0        2015/16                  1 2015-01-01 2016-01-01 2015-03-02   
1        2015/16                  1 2015-01-01 2016-01-01 2015-03-02   

       date2  
0 2016-03-01  
1 2016-03-01
```

Comment: That's great. Thank you. Clear explanation.

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck!